# Create a style for autoshapes

Tags: microsoft-word

I need to enter hundreds of colored circles into the cells of a large table. The are four different circles each representing their own thing with their own color. I'm not sure exactly how the client will want them formatted, so I'd like to be able to update them all at once like you do with styles. I'm using words autoshape tools to create the circle. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I could only suggest you to use text-mode circles like this one: ●